# updating record in yii2 with condition but not working

Tags: activerecord, yii2, find, yii2-advanced-app

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\Subscriber;
use common\models\SubscriberSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * SubscriberController implements the CRUD actions for Subscriber model.
 */
class SubscriberController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * Creates a new Subscriber model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSubscribe()
    {
        $model = new Subscriber();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'You have successfully subscribed My-Blog. You will get notification whenever New post is published');

                return $this->goHome();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry, we are unable to subscribe for the provided email address.');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Subscriber model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Subscriber the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */`enter code here`

}
```

using following model :

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\db\Expression;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "subscriber".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $token
 * @property int $status
 * @property int $created_at
 * @property int $updated_at
 */
class Subscriber extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    const STATUS_DEACTIVE = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'subscriber';
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
                ],
                'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['email'], 'required'],
            [['status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
            [['email'], 'string', 'max' => 60],
            [['token'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['token'], 'unique'],
            [['email'], 'unique',  'targetClass' => '\common\models\Subscriber', 'message' => 'This email has already subscribed our blog.','filter' => ['!=','status' ,0]],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'token' => 'Token',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Generates subscriber token
     */
    public function generateSubscriberToken()
    {
       return $this->token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Send Email when successfully subscribe
     */

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        $subscribers = Subscriber::find()->where(['email' => $this->email, 'status' => 0,])->one();

        if(!$subscribers)
        {
            $this->generateSubscriberToken();
            if(!$this->save())
            {
                return false;
            }

            return Yii::$app->mailer
            ->compose()
            ->setFrom(['noreply@my-blog.com' => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
            ->setTo('piyush@localhost')
            ->setSubject('Subscription : ' . Yii::$app->name)
            ->setHtmlBody('Thank you '.$this->email.' for subscribing '.Yii::$app->name.'<br /><br /> You will receive notification whenever new trick or post is published to website')
            ->send();

        }

        $subscribers->generateSubscriberToken();
        $subscribers->status = 1;

        if(!$subscribers->save())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Yii::$app->mailer
        ->compose()
        ->setFrom(['noreply@my-blog.com' => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
        ->setTo('piyush@localhost')
        ->setSubject('Subscription : ' . Yii::$app->name)
        ->setHtmlBody('Welcome back '.$this->email.'Thank you for subscribing '.Yii::$app->name.'<br /><br /> You will receive notification whenever new trick or post is published to website')
        ->send();
    }
}
```

This controller and model are being used to make subscribe activity using email. I want that IF a user has unsubscribed and after some time again want to subscribe then update status = 1 and regenerate token. Above `sendEmail` is working fine if it's a new subscriber but if it is an old subscriber with `status 0` then not working.

Comment: Please describe in detail what is not working (is there an error, are the emails not sent, etc.)

Comment: added an answer for you see if it helps

Comment: email is not working and not updating record also but @ time of insert, insert and email both working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above all, you need to replace the  lines

```
$subscribers->generateSubscriberToken();
$subscribers->status = 1;
```

with

```
$subscriber->token =$this->generateSubscriberToken();
$subscribers->status = 1;
```

as in your function you are setting `$this->token` and returning it and to update the record you need to set the `$subcribers->token` filed with the value.

And you should not search the table for the email with `status 0` just query the `email` and check in `PHP` if `status ==0` because a new record should only be entered if the email does not exist, without caring what the `status` field has so in your case if the email exists but with `status =1` your query won't fetch the record and it will try to insert a record instead of doing nothing.

To understand you can try using `var_dump(!$subscribers)` in both cases an see what it returns.

Moreover, you are repeating things like sending email and token generation you should change your function to the below.

```
 public function sendEmail()
    {
        $subscribers = self::find()->where(['email' => $this->email])->one();

        //set flag for sending email
        $sendMail = false;
        //email subject
        $subject = '';

        //generate token
        $token = $this->generateSubscriberToken();

        //if email found in subscribers
        if ($subscribers !== null) {

            //check if inactive
            if ($subscribers->status !== self::STATUS_ACTIVE) {

                //assign token
                $subscribers->token = $token;

                //set status to active
                $subscribers->status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;

                //update the recrod
                if (!$subscribers->save()) {
                    return false;
                }

                //set subject
                $subject = 'Welcome back ' . $this->email . 'Thank you for subscribing ' . Yii::$app->name . '<br /><br /> You will receive notification whenever new trick or post is published to website';
                $sendMail = true;
            }
        } else { //if email does not exist only then insert a new record
            $this->status = 1;
            if (!$this->save()) {

                return false;
            }
            $subject = 'Thank you ' . $this->email . ' for subscribing ' . Yii::$app->name . '<br /><br /> You will receive notification whenever new trick or post is published to website';
            $sendMail = true;
        }

        //check if send mail flag set
        if ($sendMail) {
            return Yii::$app->mailer
                ->compose()
                ->setFrom(['noreply@my-blog.com' => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
                ->setTo('piyush@localhost')
                ->setSubject('Subscription : ' . Yii::$app->name)
                ->setHtmlBody($subject)
                ->send();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, Your logic is absolutely correct but getting following error :
Creating default object from empty value
$subcribers->status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;

Comment: oops! it was a typo it should be `$subscribers` instead of `$subcribers` the letter `s` is missing after `$sub` i updated the code @PiyushGupta

Comment: still not working. In actionSubscribe() else part is executing : 

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'You have successfully subscribed My-Blog. You will get notification whenever New post is published');

                return $this->goHome();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry, we are unable to subscribe for the provided email address.');
            }
        }
I am getting else part message

Comment: is this happening when trying to subscribe with a member whi is already subscribed and active ? @PiyushGupta

Comment: No this is happening when a member is trying to subscribe but already subscribed but not active

Comment: that's must be because your record is not validated when calling `$subscribers->save()`  try adding `print_r($model->errors)` inside the check `if(!$subscribers->save()){` and comment out `return false;` for a moment @PiyushGupta

Comment: I did that you told . It's not printing any error and sending email but not updating record in dtabase

Comment: it should be `$subscribers->errors` not `$model->errors` sorry and how come it is sending email but not updating the record if the record is not updated `$subscribers->save()` will return false and email will not be sent as it will go inside the `if` and `return false` from there to the action.

Comment: I did print_r($subscribers->errors) inside the check if(!$subscribers->save()){ and commented return false; but still same error. Email is working because i have commented return false inside check if(!$subscribers->save())

Comment: `code$this->createTable('subscriber', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'email' => $this->string(60)->notNull()->unique(),
            'token' => $this->string()->unique(),
            'status' => $this->smallInteger()->notNull()->defaultValue(1),
            'created_at' => $this->datetime()->notNull(),
            'updated_at' => $this->datetime()->notNull(),
        ]);`code

This is subscriber table schema.. please check if any error in this while updating

Comment: sorry for late reply did you managed to find where it was going wrong i could not look into it was in office @PiyushGupta

Comment: Yes I found, THere was mistake in validation rule. I defined created_at, updated_at as integer in rule(), I changed rule for these from integer to safe , Now it's working fine.

Thank you @muhammad to support me .

Comment: I also have problem in the same module. I have generated question please check :

Comment: yeah, i just added a comment there can you select this answer or vote up if it helped you in any case . @PiyushGupta